# what's a practical approach for putting an angular test framework in place?

Tags: angular

the ng testing guide has 150 printed pages:  https://angular.io/guide/testing. I remember when I was trying to figure out how to configure aot for my ng app. I reviewed 35 printed  pages of documentation (https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler). then I realized through the advice of other ng devs that I could use a simple cli cmd to do the aot compile.

are there any similarities with ng test configuation?  ie although ng.io has 150 printed pages of documentation in their test guide, there's actually a relatively quick and easy way to put a basic test framework in place for my app?

Comment: See the *Setup* section in the test guide.

Comment: Angular cli adds a testing framework for both unit and e2e testing. Also, it generates a basic test spec for each generated component which you can follow. Still, it is worth reading at least some of the basic angular specific testing concepts, just to get a good direction.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell whether what I am going to suggest is practical or not, depending on *your current setup*. What *I* did in our project was a full-swipe code migration.

## Step 1: Scaffold

I used [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to scaffold a blank project, which by default has several things presetup:

- [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/index.html) test runner, [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/) unit test framework, and [Istanbul](https://github.com/tao-zeng/karma-istanbul) code coverage.
- [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) end-to-end ("browser") tests.
- [TSLint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint) for checking code in TypeScript code.
- [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) for obfuscation, minification, and bundling the compiled JavaScript code.

## Step 2: Move/copy the code

This stage will require 4 to 12 hours of pure time (tops!). Just carefully copy your existing code to `src` directory of the new blank project. Make sure to

- update your root module (`AppModule`);
- revisit `<router-outlet>` in `app.component.html` or it's equivalent;
- resolve the compilation issues;
- whatever else you see...

It took me about day and a half to move a ~40 components (medium size) project to setup on the new rails. And I had just a bit of experience with Angular configuration/infrastructure back then. If you have even bigger project or even less experience, you may actually reserve 1-4 days for this activity, but IMHO it's still very very cheap and pragmatic option to get your project up-to-speed (as in "ready to go") with several important technologies I listed above. This is especially true if you compare this way with the effort required to set all those things up manually. I went that route and our entire team is very happy with the result.